# Autotools build fails due to subdir-objects option in AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake, libtool

I'm currently working on a C++ project which relies on recursive automake for building. 
I want to build a shared library and the `Makefile.am` in the `src` directory of the library looks like

```
# ...

# Library name
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libadapter-@MY_API_VERSION@.la

# Sources
libadapter_@MY_API_VERSION@_la_SOURCES = \
    $(top_builddir)/src/sourceA.cpp \
    $(top_builddir)/src/sourceB.cpp

# ...
```

Since version 1.14, automake issues a warning when the `subdir-objects` option is not specified in `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` in `configure.ac`. However, adding the `subdir-objects` option seems to break the build process with `make` complaining about missing `.Plo` files. I already searched the web for people experiencing similar problems but did not find any sensible hint on how to resolve the issue without changing the project to a non-recursive one. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Diving more deeply into the problem, I noted that `./configure` creates a directory literally named `$(top_builddir)` below the current source directory of the library, which contains all the required `.Plo` files for building the library. In the `Makefile`, however, I found that the `.Plo` equivalents of my library sources (`sourceA.cpp` and `sourceB.cpp` in the example) are prefixed by `include $(top_builddir)/src/$(DEPDIR)/` and `$(top_builddir)` is a variable defined as a *relative* path (namely, `../../../src/.deps/`). Now it becomes clear why `make` can't find the `.Plo` files because it searches the wrong directory. This looks like a possible duplicate of bug [#16375](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-automake/2014-01/msg00005.html). Any workarounds?

**EDIT 2:**
Digging further in the web revealed two more threads which address the issue: [#1327](http://mytestbed.net/issues/1327) and [automake-bug](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-automake/2004-01/msg00044.html). A known workaround seems to be passing the `--disable-dependency-tracking` option to `./configure`. At least for me it works.

Comment: Are you using [relative paths](https://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/automake/nonrecursive.html) for the SOURCES?

Comment: FWIW, I get this message too with automake 1.14 (non-recursive build, no relative paths).  Currently, my strategy is to ignore the warning until I find a way to not goof up the build.  Seems to build OK (for now...).

Comment: @ldav1s - Interesting. Do you use ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in top-level Makefile.am? What about the AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE options?

Comment: I use `ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS` just to set the macro path (`-I ...`).  The `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` options are set by `AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS`: `1.11 foreign`.  That's it.

Comment: OTOH, maybe I'm _not_ using relative paths.  Maybe I have to switch `top_srcdir` to `abs_top_srcdir` and `top_builddir` to `abs_top_builddir`.  Hmm...

Comment: @ldav1s - Sounds about the same as what I use. Don't seem to have any trouble with `top_builddir` or `top_srcdir`, but this issue seems to be popping up with 1.14.x in a lot of places.

Comment: @ldav1s - Actually, it looks like a warning to smooth the transition to 2.0, which will "unconditionally activate the 'subdir-objects' option..." (in the automake NEWS file).

Comment: @Marcel - if you could provide the offending `Makefile.am`?

Comment: @Brett I added the contents of the `Makefile.am` to my question.

Comment: @ldav1s I also tried changing from `top_builddir` to `abs_top_builddir` but get the same error (missing `.Plo` files).

Comment: @Brett Answering your first comment: Yes, I did use relative paths but also tried absolute paths (see my previous comment) but still get the same error (missing `.Plo` files). Do you see any problems in using relative paths?

Comment: @BrettHale, I remember reading that NEWS file a couple months ago when I ran into this issue the first time I tried building with automake 1.14.  Then I remember trying `subdir-objects`, which broke my build.

Comment: Can you tell me the detailed steps to solve it because I have met the same problem. And I am a Chinese student at libproess ，I can't understand what they wrote bellow.

Comment: I had exact same issue, with automake-1.14.1.   Originally I had `libMyLib_la_SOURCES=$(top_srcdir)/external/http_parser.c` which failed (it created a directory called top_srcdir).  I replaced it with a relative path and it worked:  `libMyLib_la_SOURCES=../external/http_parser.c`.  Also added the `subdir-objects` as advised.

Answer (score 11):

From the `automake-1.14.1` `NEWS` file:

```
The next major Automake version (2.0) will unconditionally activate
the 'subdir-objects' option.  In order to smooth out the transition,
we now give a warning (in the category 'unsupported') whenever a
source file is present in a subdirectory but the 'subdir-object' is
not enabled.  For example, the following usage will trigger such a
warning:

        bin_PROGRAMS = sub/foo
        sub_foo_SOURCES = sub/main.c sub/bar.c
```

So in preparation for this, you need `subdir-objects` as one of the options in `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE`, if you use subdirectories in 'object' names as described above. This option will be 'on' by default in 2.0.

If you could provide the `Makefile.am` for the directory that fails, it might provide a clue as to why the relative directories aren't matching up.

---

Ok, there a couple of things about this `Makefile.am`. Firstly, there are ways to correctly version a libtool library, and `@MY_API_VERSION@` substitutions aren't the way to go. You could form a numeric string for example, in `configure.ac`, followed by **`AC_SUBST(MY_API_VERSION)`**.

In `Makefile.am` : **`libadapter_la_LDFLAGS = -release $(MY_API_VERSION)`** will put this information in the `libadapter.la` libtool meta-file.

For *serious* version control, where interface compatibility, revisions, binary compatibility, etc., are desirable, you can have a look at the libtool reference on [versioning](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#Versioning). Important system libraries, particularly GNOME/GTK (look at their `configure.ac` files!), go all-out on this stuff. I certainly don't, unless I'm considering releasing something into the wild. I still find it confusing.

Omitting `@MY_API_VERSION@`, you can also stick with **`libadapter_la_SOURCES`**. However, the source files aren't found relative to any `builddir` path, which was perhaps the source of your `.Plo` file issue. The `builddir` variables describe where the *built* components are found - you can also build out-of-tree, and this is a good test to see if your automake setup is robust. Some packages promote this, e.g., go to the top of the package, make a directory there called `build` or `my_build` or whatever suits:

`cd my_build; ../configure <options>; make`

The package, it's source tree and recursive directories will be left alone, everything will be built under the `my_build` directory, and the subdirectories will mirror those of your source tree, only they will be full of built objects, libraries, executables, etc. `make install` should also work perfectly using the generated `my_build/Makefile`.

But returning to the point - those source files are relative to the `$(srcdir)` directory, which corresponds to the current (recursive) `Makefile.am`'s directory. The various `builddir` and `srcdir` variables are described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Preset-Output-Variables).

If your `src` directory is located under the top-level directory, you could use: `"$(top_srcdir)/src/sourceA.cpp"` - notice that `"$(srcdir)/src/sourceA.cpp"` would be *wrong*, as it would be like specifying `"$(top_srcdir)/src/src/sourceA.cpp"` in this case.

You *could* use `"$(srcdir)/sourceA.cpp"`, but this directory is implicit anyway. All you need is:

**`libadapter_la_SOURCES = sourceA.cpp sourceB.cpp`**

It is also perfectly acceptable to put any header files in the `src` directory used by `libadapter` in the `SOURCES` list. A change of a header will rebuild what's required.

---

Anyway, I didn't mean to write this much, but I know how frustrating it is get clear information about the autotools. The [Autotools Mythbuster](https://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/) provides excellent 'walk-through' tutorials, and stays very up to date.

Comment: I already was aware of this snippet from the `automake` `NEWS` file but from what I understand, `automake` should work smoothly if the `subdir-objects` option is simply added to `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` in `configure.ac` - no matter if relative or absolute paths are used in `Makefile.am`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Marcel - I've tried to address the issues in your `Makefile.am`. I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for this exhaustive answer. I see the difference between `top_srcdir` and `top_builddir` but I don't understand why exchanging the latter by the former should make any difference for in-tree builds, which is what I do at the moment. Also, omitting the `MY_API_VERSION` should not contribute to resolving the issue. In the meantime, I think I have found the reason for the failing build, see my updated question.

Comment: Yes, I did, but without any effect - the error remains.

Comment: Adding "subdir-objects" to my AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE fixed my issue. thanks.