# Using identical source files for multiple libraries with GNU Autotools

Tags: autotools

I'm working on a C/C++ project where I use the GNU Autotools for building. My directory structure is as follows:

```
..
adapter/
    libraryA/
        include/
        src/
        ..
    libraryB/
        include/
        src/
        ..            
    ..
src/
    Log.cpp
    ..
```

Besides `libraryA` and `libraryB`, I also have one library at the top level, call it `libraryMain`, which all use the same `Log.cpp` from `src`. If I'm building out-of-source with the `--disable-dependency-tracking` option passed to `configure` (see also my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609580/autotools-build-fails-due-to-subdir-objects-option-in-am-init-automake)), `libtool` complains

> libtool: link: `Log.lo' is not a valid libtool object

when linking `libraryMain` because a `Log.lo` was generated in `src` when building `libraryA` and `libraryB` which is then referenced by `libraryMain`. If I manually remove `Log.lo` from `src` and rebuild `libraryMain`, everything works fine because `libraryMain` generates its own `Log.lo` in `build/src`.

To make things more clear, my `Makefile.am` for `libraryMain` (located in `src`) looks as follows:

```
..
libcomana_@COMANA_API_VERSION@_la_SOURCES = \
    .. \
    Log.cpp
..
```

while the `Makefile.am` for `libraryA` (located in `adapter/libraryA/src`) is

```
..
libraryA_la_SOURCES = \
    .. \
    $(top_srcdir)/src/Log.cpp
..
```

I already understood that the problem is due to the libraries in `adapter` not placing their generated `.lo` files in their own directory but directly under the `src` directory in the project's root directory. I would actually assume that no libtool objects are placed in the source tree but rather in the build tree as is also done for `libraryMain`. As a first workaround, I created a symlink to `src/Log.cpp` in `adapter/libraryA/src` and `adapter/libraryB/src` but I think that this is probably not very elegant. I really hope I have made myself clear enough. I really appreciate any comments on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think my question might have been a bit unclear. To wrap up, I circumvented the problem by omitting the `--disable-dependency-tracking` option and changing the my `Makefile.am`s to not include any sources prefixed by `$(srcdir)` or `$(top_srcdir)` because this seems to confuse `automake`, at least when building out-of-source (see also my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609580/autotools-build-fails-due-to-subdir-objects-option-in-am-init-automake) or [this](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=13928) bug report). Although I don't know if this is the right place for this, I decided to set up a small example, which works correctly and avoids the problems I described in my question.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
autogen.sh
configure.ac
Makefile.am
adapter
    Makefile.am
    adapterA
        Makefile.am
        include
            foo.h
        src
            foo.cpp
            Makefile.am                
    adapterB
        Makefile.am
        include
            foo.h
        src
            foo.cpp
            Makefile.am
debug
include
    hello.h
m4
src
    hello.cpp
    helloconf.sh.in
    Makefile.am
```

The files contain the following code:

`autogen.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# GNU autotools toolchain
libtoolize --automake
aclocal
autoheader
automake --add-missing --force-missing --gnu
autoconf
```

`configure.ac`:

```
dnl Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.

dnl Project name and version
AC_INIT([hello], [0.1])

dnl Library version information
AC_SUBST([HELLO_API_VERSION], [0.1])
AC_SUBST([HELLO_SO_VERSION], [0:0:0])

dnl Create a separate header with C preprocessor `#define` statements
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

dnl Look for auxiliary scripts in the current directory
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([.])

dnl Automake initialization
dnl -Wall Show warnings
dnl -Wall Treat warnings as errors
dnl subdir-objects Place generated object files (.o) into the same as 
dnl                directory their source files, in order to avoid 
dnl                collisions when non-recursive make is used
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall subdir-objects])
m4_ifdef([AM_PROG_AR], [AM_PROG_AR])

dnl Libtool settings
LT_INIT([disable-static])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])

dnl Doxygen
dnl DX_HTML_FEATURE(ON)
dnl DX_PDF_FEATURE(OFF)
dnl DX_INIT_DOXYGEN([$PACKAGE_NAME], [Doxyfile], [doc])

dnl Checks for programs
AC_PROG_CXX([g++])
AC_PROG_INSTALL
AC_PROG_LN_S
AM_PROG_LIBTOOL

dnl Use the C++ compiler for the following checks
AC_LANG([C++])

dnl Checks for libraries

dnl Checks for header files
AC_HEADER_STDC
AC_CHECK_HEADER(iostream)

dnl Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T

dnl Checks for library functions

dnl Compiler and linker flags
AC_SUBST([AM_CXXFLAGS], [-Wall]) # C++
AC_SUBST([AM_LDFLAGS], [-Wall]) # ld (Linker)

dnl Libraries
AC_SUBST([LIBS])

AC_CONFIG_FILES(
    Makefile
    adapter/Makefile
    adapter/adapterA/Makefile
    adapter/adapterA/src/Makefile
    adapter/adapterB/Makefile
    adapter/adapterB/src/Makefile
    src/Makefile
    src/helloconf.sh
)

AC_OUTPUT
```

`Makefile.am`:

```
# Process this file with automake to produce Makefile.in

# Independent executable script for inclusion in the distribution archive
dist_noinst_SCRIPTS = autogen.sh

# Look for additional autoconf macros in the m4 subdirectory
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = \
    -I m4 \
    @ACLOCAL_FLAGS@

# Subdirectories
SUBDIRS = \
    adapter \
    src 

# Entire directories copied recursively into the distribution
EXTRA_DIST = 

# Delete anything except for files required to run `./configure && make`
MAINTAINERCLEANFILES = 

# Delete anything which should not be part of the distribution
DISTCLEANFILES =
```

`adapter/Makefile.am`:

```
# Process this file with automake to produce Makefile.in

SUBDIRS = \
    adapterA \
    adapterB
```

`adapter/adapterA/Makefile.am`:

```
# Process this file with automake to produce Makefile.in

SUBDIRS = src
```

`adapter/adapterA/include/foo.h`:

```
#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_

void foo();

#endif
```

`adapter/adapterA/src/foo.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "foo.h"

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, foo from adapterA" << std::endl;
}
```

`adapter/adapterA/src/Makefile.am`:

```
# Process this file with automake to produce Makefile.in

# Adapter .so version
ADAPTER_SO_VERSION = 0:0:0

AM_CXXFLAGS = \
    -I$(top_srcdir)/include \
    -I$(srcdir)/../include \
    @AM_CXXFLAGS@

# Library name
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libadapter-@HELLO_API_VERSION@.la

# Sources
libadapter_@HELLO_API_VERSION@_la_SOURCES = \
    ../../../src/hello.cpp \
    foo.cpp

# Linker flags    
libadapter_@HELLO_API_VERSION@_la_LDFLAGS = \
    -version-info $(ADAPTER_SO_VERSION)

# Include directory and headers
libadapter_@HELLO_API_VERSION@_la_includedir = \
    $(exec_prefix)/include/adapter/adapterA
libadapter_@HELLO_API_VERSION@_la_include_HEADERS = \
    ../include/foo.h

# Library install directory
libdir = $(exec_prefix)/lib/adapter/adapterA
```

`adapter/adapterB/Makefile.am` and `adapter/adapterB/include/foo.h` are identical to their `A` equivalents.

`adapter/adapterB/src/foo.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "foo.h"

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, foo from adapterB" << std::endl;
}
```

`adapter/adapterB/src/Makefile.am`:

```
# Process this file with automake to produce Makefile.in

# Adapter .so version
ADAPTER_SO_VERSION = 0:0:0

AM_CXXFLAGS = \
    -I$(top_srcdir)/include \
    -I$(srcdir)/../include \
    @AM_CXXFLAGS@

# Library name
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libadapter-@HELLO_API_VERSION@.la

# Sources
libadapter_@HELLO_API_VERSION@_la_SOURCES = \
    ../../../src/hello.cpp \
    foo.cpp

# Linker flags    
libadapter_@HELLO_API_VERSION@_la_LDFLAGS = \
    -version-info $(ADAPTER_SO_VERSION)

# Include directory and headers
libadapter_@HELLO_API_VERSION@_la_includedir = \
    $(exec_prefix)/include/adapter/adapterB
libadapter_@HELLO_API_VERSION@_la_include_HEADERS = \
    ../include/foo.h

# Library install directory
libdir = $(exec_prefix)/lib/adapter/adapterB
```

`include/hello.h`:

```
#ifndef HELLO_H_
#define HELLO_H_

void hello();

#endif
```

`src/hello.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "hello.h"

void hello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

`src/helloconf.sh.in`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo @prefix@
```

`src/Makefile.am`:

```
# Process this file with automake to produce Makefile.in

# Look for additional autoconf macros in the m4 subdirectory
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = \
    -I m4 \
    @ACLOCAL_FLAGS@

# Compiler flags
AM_CXXFLAGS = \
    -I$(top_srcdir)/include \
    @AM_CXXFLAGS@

# Library name
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libhello-@HELLO_API_VERSION@.la

# Sources
libhello_@HELLO_API_VERSION@_la_SOURCES = \
    hello.cpp

# Libraries
libhello_@HELLO_API_VERSION@_la_LDFLAGS = \
    -version-info $(HELLO_SO_VERSION)
libhello_@HELLO_API_VERSION@_la_LIBADD = @LTLIBOBJS@

# Include directory and headers
libhello_@HELLO_API_VERSION@_la_includedir = $(includedir)

libhello_@HELLO_API_VERSION@_la_include_HEADERS = \
    $(top_srcdir)/include/hello.h

# Data
helloconf_DATA = helloconf.sh
helloconfdir = $(exec_prefix)/bin
EXTRA_DIST = $(helloconf_DATA)
```

P.S.: I know it might have been better to upload an archive but I wanted to keep everything in one place.