# fail to build libprocess, something wrong with the autotools

Tags: autotools

I download the libprocess from https://github.com/3rdparty/libprocess, and then I follow the build commands, run:

```
./bootstrap
```

there will be an warning says:

```
Makefile.am:97: warning: source file 'src/tests/time_tests.cpp' is in a subdirectory,
Makefile.am:97: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
```

so I've added the 'subdir-objects' in the configure.ac file :

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror -Wno-portability foreign subdir-objects])
```

now the ./bootstrap go smoothly, but when I mkdir "build", and run "../configure; make" in the "build" dir, it failed with:

```
Making all in 3rdparty
Makefile:879: gmock-1.6.0/src/.deps/libgmock_la-gmock-all.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:880: gmock-1.6.0/gtest/src/.deps/libgmock_la-gtest-all.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:881: ry-http-parser-1c3624a/.deps/libry_http_parser_la-http_parser.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:882: stout/tests/.deps/stout_tests-bytes_tests.Po: No such file or directory
Makefile:883: stout/tests/.deps/stout_tests-duration_tests.Po: No such file or directory
```

I've found that, in the build/3rdparty dir, there are directories:

```
$(GMOCK)
$(GTEST)
$(RY_HTTP_PARSER)
$(STOUT)
```

so I think the problem is that the $(GMOCK) should be translate to gmock-1.6.0 in the configure process, however it didn't.

But I can't find the way to fix the bug, please anyone give me some clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so I've added the 'subdir-objects' in the configure.ac file

This is likely your problem.  Your `bootstrap` problem is just a warning.

Recent versions of of automake will give this error for non-recursive Makefile.am, [like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609580/autotools-build-fails-due-to-subdir-objects-option-in-am-init-automake).

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I need!